# What is the fastest way to level an account?

Tags: league-of-legends

I'm planning to start a smurf account in League of Legends. Given that I have 2-4 friends playing with me, what would be the fastest way to get level 30? Is it more efficient to play bot games?

Comment: Bot games != using bots.Bot games = games vs. KI.

Comment: The problem is that smurfing is not ethical. If you smurf your MMR will be low while the MMR on your **real** account is higher.

Comment: Where do i state that we are 5 uberpros who want to crush newbies?

Comment: **Smurfing itself** is not ethic since you will get **MMR advantage** over your opponents by definition. Period.

Comment: @AdamArold This is not true. A smurf will eventually (within 10-20 games) get to the MMR he deserves, so he will be matched against other smurfs.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The fastest way would be Playing COOP VS AI-games on intermediate level until you reach level 14 (You gain normal experience until then). At level 15 the exp gain will be lowered from bot games if you've already played more than 180 minutes of bot-games per day, so you have to play normals. There are 2 options:

- If you know that your 5v5 games last rather long, play 3v3 since these are usually much shorter.
- If you know that you easily win games fast always play 5v5 since these give alot more experience if they don't last too long. After 40 minutes it's not worth though. Two 3v3 games that last less than 20 minutes will give you more experience than a 40minute 5v5 game.

Also remember to buy EXP boosts. If you win more than 4 games per day you should take Timed boosts over Per-Win boosts.

Comment: IP boosts are helpful too! That way you have plenty of IP for champs, runes, and rune pages once you hit 30.

Answer (score -1):

Honestly levelling in League of Legends can be tedious and without buying XP boosts could take you a very long time. The [fastest ways to level 30](https://www.lol-smurfs.com/blog/fastest-way-level-30) are covered in this blog post but the general key points are:

Experience boosts (duration): Duration experience boosts give you bonus exp for a set number of games, regardless of if you win or lose. The best value boost is for 7 days and costs 520RP, or around $5. Depending on how often you play, you might need several of these before you reach level 30. You should be able to reach level 30 within a month using these boosts.

Experience boosts (wins): These experience boosts give bonus exp every time you win a game - but will give you nothing if you lose. The best value boost is for 50 wins and costs 980RP, or around $10. You'll need at least 2 of these to reach level 30. They can also be combined with duration boosts for bigger exp gains.

Playing normal games: Normal PvP games give much better experience rates than bot games. However, you will likely win around 50% of your normal games on your way to level 30, whereas you will probably win closer to 100% of your bot games. Without boosts it can take upwards of 250 normal games to reach the required experience for level 30 - that could be up to 250 hours of playtime! Definitely not quick if you aren't using experience boosts.

Comment: Bot games are the fastest way to get EXP.  They don't get reduced exp until around 20 or so.  This means that since they give the same EXP, the games are shorter, AND you are almost guaranteed to win that bot games are far superior to level until then.  I would never suggest to someone to purchase an account.  In addition to being immoral, you can get the account banned for buying it, or the original owner can just get the account back through their email and you get nothing.